# Exporting large numbers to a text file

Tags: export, text

I need to export large numbers to an ASCII text file, but as simple digits without powers of ten, e.g. I need to write 123456.789 to the file and not 1.23456789E10^5. It seems like such a simple thing, but I can't figure it out without some serious kludge. Is there a neat way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Something like `Export["test.txt", 
 ToString@AccountingForm[123456123456.789, 20]]` ?

Comment: Thanks cormullion, Chris Degnan's longform[] does exactly this

Comment: You can use `NumberForm` with the option `ExponentFunction`: `NumberForm[123456.789, {20, 3}, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]`